# Connectivity issue between GAE and Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

anyone having cloud sql and GAE connectivity issue? I have an existing DB instance, i found that all my AUTHORIZED APP ENGINE APPLICATIONS was deleted, and you cannot add any. It always empty after save. This is causing error at my application. Any idea?

There are the Java error I get:

1 error: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this for you. This is a bug in the web interface :( We are doing the best we can to have a fix out as quickly as possible. Thank you for the report and please accept our apologies for the inconvenience.

You should still be able to add authorized applications via the [Google Cloud SDK](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/).